# if statement not working php

Tags: php, post, if-statement

I have php that consists of an if statement followed by several elseif statements. For some reason i cannot get the if statement to ever return a true value and output the corresponding message. It has nothing to do with (I think) the $_POST method because all of the elseif statements work with their $_POST methods. I want the if statement to return a true value if nothing has been entered in the corresponding field.

```
if(!isset($_POST['phpro_username'],$_POST['phpro_password'], 
        $_POST['phpro_password1']))
{
    $message = 'Please enter a valid username and password';
}
/*check to make sure the form is the one 
 * from the browser*/
elseif ($_POST['form_token'] != $_SESSION['form_token'])
{
    $message = 'Invalid Form Submission';
}
elseif (strlen($_POST['phpro_username']) > 20 || 
        strlen($_POST['phpro_username']) < 4 ) 
{
    $message = 'Username Invalid';
}
```

There are a few other elseif statements after this, and if any of the elseif statements are not true then i get the correct message. Its just the first if statement that does not work. Here is my code for posting the variables (password/username)

```
<form id="signup_form" action="adduser_submit.php" method="post">
<fieldset>
<p class="loginfield" id="Username">
<label for="phpro_username">Create Username</label><br>
<input type="text" id="phpro_username" name="phpro_username" value="" maxlength="20" />
</p>

<p class="loginfield" id="Password">
<label for="phpro_password">Create Password</label><br>
<input type="text" id="phpro_password" name="phpro_password" value="" maxlength="20" />
</p>

<p class="loginfield" id="Re-enter Password">
    <label for="phpro_password1">Re-enter Password</label><br>
<input type="text" id="phpro_password1" name="phpro_password1" value="" maxlength="20" />
</p>

<p>
<input type="hidden" name="form_token" value="<?php echo $form_token; ?>" />

<div id="submit_button" >
<input type="submit" value="&rarr; Sign Up" />
</div>
</p>

</fieldset>
</form>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Don't use Snippet for non-html/js/css code. Fixed it for ya this time.

Comment: Is that even valid PHP?

Comment: @cybermonkey Which part? Seems valid to me...

Comment: @MightyPork first time using this site, i didnt see a snippet deal for php?

Comment: @Anonymous.X i just came across empty() after i submitted this, i tested it out and it seems to work fine

Comment: @ratrace123 there is none, you just use the `{}` button, which indents it by four spaces, that marks code. The snippet functionality is not for php.

Comment: @MightyPork great thanks will do next time, appreciate the help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your problem is that [`isset`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) is not what you expect it to be. If you send a form with empty fields they will still be set in `$_POST`.

You want to check if they are [`empty`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php):

```
if(empty($_POST['phpro_username']) || empty($_POST['phpro_password']) || empty($_POST['phpro_password1'])) {
    //...
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, i was suspicious of this once @Anonymous.X above mentioned the empty field

Comment: @ratrace123 Didn't you check your PHP log for errors? If you did it should've shown.

Comment: @cybermonkey yea i read through them and it seems like the code that i have should be working..